# What is a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

Following program give me runtime error(Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int& bar()
{
    int n = 10;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int& i = bar();
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My teacher told me it is a undefined behavior because dangling reference. Is he right? 
If yes then how to avoid it?

Comment: There's gotta be a good duplicate for this.

Comment: Yes, your computer is right when it complains about computer stuff. So, what **is** the exact error? Copy and paste the error message into your question. And I'm not sure you get a *runtime* error; your compiler should already be warning you.

Comment: @KillerDeath `endl` is for new line formatting in `cout`

Comment: @tkausl I asked about "Dangling reference" . Not "Dangling Pointer". Pointer and reference are different things.

Comment: In short, you return reference to local variable of function. When function returns, local variable ceases to exist, and the returned reference becomes dangling: it does not reference a valid variable. Solution: return value, not reference, or allocate object from heap and return a (smart) pointer.

Comment: I know, but the answers in the other question are equally true for references.

Comment: Marked as duplicate, since there is a distinct relationship between a pointer and a reference that refer to the same object.  A dangling reference is a reference to an object that does not exist, or no longer exists.  A dangling pointer is a pointer to an object that does not exist, or no longer exists.  Dereferencing a dangling pointer (e.g.  `*dangling_p`) produces a dangling reference.  Computing the address of (the object referenced by) a dangling reference (i.e. `&dangling_reference`) produces a dangling pointer.

Comment: Duping "dangling reference" to "dangling pointer" is not incorrect from an academic perspective, but seems rather unhelpful. Even though most answers apply roughly also to references, I don't think it actually helps anyone who doesn't already understand pointers, references and their dangling counterparts pretty well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is indeed an undefined behavior because you are returning a reference to automatic variable which will be destroyed when execution of `bar()` completes

You can avoid it by writing:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int& bar()
{
    static int n = 10;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int& i = bar();
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case static variable `n` will not be destroyed when execution of `bar()` completes, it will be destroyed when your program terminates.

Comment: Note that using a static variable forfeits thread-safety.