# Compiler Removes Vector Returned By Reference

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, pass-by-reference, release

Not quite sure why this is happening but I have the following code:

```
vector<glm::vec3>& HeightMap::Vec3Vertices() {
    vector<glm::vec3> vecs;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i += 3) {
        vecs.push_back(glm::vec3(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]));
    }
    return vecs;
}
```

Now later in my main code I have:

```
vector<glm::vec3>& vertices = hm.Vec3Vertices();
```

Where `hm` is a Height Map object.

I'm in **Release Mode**

I use `vertices` later and when I do the size is correct but all the data within it is unreadable. When I step through the code it appears as though the compiler has optimized out the initialization of the `vecs` in `Vec3Vertices()`

On the other hand if I change it so that I do not pass by reference

`vector<glm::vec3> HeightMap::Vec3Vertices() {`

and

`vector<glm::vec3> vertices = hm.Vec3Vertices();`

It all works perfectly. Any ideas on why this might be? I am aware that passing by value will probably result in the compiler using a move operation anyways, I just can't for the life of me figure out why my pass by reference is invalid in the first place. Thanks in advance

Comment: **Never** return a reference to a local object.  The object gets destroyed when the function ends.

Comment: You return a dangling reference. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46011510/1896169

Comment: But a vector is just a pointer to data on the heap so why can't I pass it back? I mean the data stille xists on the heap doesnt it? On a similar note what semantics should I use to ensure a move is used?

Comment: Yes, and the vector's destructor deletes the pointer when it is destroyed

Comment: Because a vector is not just a pointer to data on the heap.

Comment: @Ryoku To ensure a move is used (when you return a value, not a reference), just return it. It will automatically be moved, or possibly better (sometimes the compiler can completely elide the move/copy)

Comment: @Justin okay I think I get it. The pointer is destroyed. That sucks. On the other hand I know the compiler is probably smart enough to make a  good call on it, but out of curiosity is there a way to ensure a move is used?

Comment: Actually, with C++17 your code won't even involve a move.  The code will invoke a "Return Value Optimization" which means: the caller allocates space for the return value, then the function constructs the returned object directly in that space which the caller provided.  (This is due to the specific way the function is written, in which there is a single return statement, which is returning a local variable of the same type as the function's return value.)

Comment: @Daniel thats awesome, took many a years to get that level of efficiency

Comment: @DanielSchepler Even in C++98 it would probably just be NRVO'd.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision - as far as I can tell this would still be an NRVO optimization, and still isn't a mandatory optimization in C++17.  That said, most compilers in practice would apply the NRVO optimization.

Comment: @juanchopanza even if it was, you still can't return a reference to a local pointer

Comment: @M.M There are many scenarios in which a reference to a valid object can be returned, but none of them solve the simple problem of returning something that gets created in a function without introducing ownership issues.