# Correct way to use Eigen::Transpose<const Matrix3>?

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions

I have a rotation class which can use either Quaternions or Rotation matrices to represent rotations. I have no issues when the transpose function is defined like below:

```cpp
Matrix3 Rot3::transpose() const {
  // quaternion_ is a class variable of type `Quaternion`.
  return quaternion_.toRotationMatrix().transpose();
}
```

The moment I switch to the recommended version using `Eigen::Transpose`, my unit tests fail (and I get NaNs)

```cpp
Eigen::Transpose<const Matrix3> Rot3::transpose() const {
  // quaternion_ is a class variable of type `Quaternion`.
  return quaternion_.toRotationMatrix().eval().transpose();
}
```

I need to use the `.eval()` in that weird way else the compiler complains with an obscure error message. My guess is that my use of the `Eigen::Transpose` declaration is not aligning with what I am returning. Any help or suggestions as to why this method behaves so strangely, and any recommendations for the correct way to do this?

Comment: You could simply `return quaternion_.conjugate().toRotationMatrix();` and just return by value.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Eigen::Transpose` as your return type ?

Comment: @Louen so we can take advantage of the template expression for further optimized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Eigen::Transpose`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transpose.html) is simply a **wrapper** class around an existing matrix. It keeps a reference to the matrix and relays the call to access the elements while reversing the indices. The goal of this class is to be able to use the transposed matrix without having to actually copy the matrix itself.

In other words this is a very simplified version of how the `Transpose` class is defined :

```
struct Transpose<const Matrix3> {

   const Matrix3& m_matrix;

   const float& coeffRef(int row, int col) const { 
       return m_matrix.coeffRef(col,row);
   }
}
```

You can see the actual source [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Transpose_8h_source.html).

The critical part is that the `Transpose` class stores a **reference** to the given matrix.

Now what happens in your second version of the `transpose` function ?

- you create a temporary `Matrix3` with `quaternion.toRotationMatrix().eval()`
- you then create a `Transpose` wrapper around this temporary matrix , storing a reference to this matrix.

When you return from the function the `Transpose` that you return has a reference to an object that has gone out of scope. This is called a [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011510/what-is-a-dangling-reference), which leads to undefined behavior (the reason you see `NaN`s is most likely that the memory where your temporary matrix lived has been overwritten by other data). The code is equivalent to this:

```
Eigen::Transpose<const Matrix3> Rot3::transpose() const {
  // Equivalent to your second version
  Matrix3 temp = quaternion_.toRotationMatrix().eval();
  Transpose<const Matrix3> result = temp.transpose(); // Holds ref to temp -> Leads to UB
  return result; 
}
```

Note that this doesn't happen in the first version because your return type is `Matrix3`. In this case the `Transpose` object you create is converted to a new `Matrix3` object to be returned, which does a copy of the coefficients. Here is an equivalent version of your first function.

```
Matrix3 Rot3::transpose() const {
  // Equivalent to your first version
  Matrix3 temp = quaternion_.toRotationMatrix().eval();
  Matrix3 result = temp.transpose(); // Does a full copy of the transpose of `temp`
  return result; 
}
```

If you still want to keep using `Eigen::Transpose` as your return type (maybe you *really* want to avoid the copy operation), you need to store the rotation matrix in a permanent location (e.g. as a cached `Matrix3` member variable in your class) to avoid that dangling reference problem.

Another option is to pass a pre-existing matrix to be filled e.g.

```
void Rot3::setToTranspose() (Matrix3& result)
{
     result = quaternion_.toRotationMatrix().transpose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was my suspicion as well but I couldn't find any documentation to confirm it. I'll see what the team agrees is the right thing to do.