# what does func() = var_name; assignment do in c++?

Tags: c++, function, lvalue

I was studying about l-values and r-values but I am confused with this:

```
#include<iostream>
int& get_val(){
    return 10;
}
int main(){
    get_val() = 5;
    int a = get_val();
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know about `int a = get_val();` (i.e., it will assign the returned value to the variable), but I want to know what this does: `get_val() = 5;`. What does `int& get_val()` do?

I know we cannot run this code but I want to learn the concept behind this.

Comment: You should get an error on a modern compiler: [https://ideone.com/l8XCOx](https://ideone.com/l8XCOx)

Comment: Where did you find this?  The code should not compile.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: If `get_val` returned a reference to some variable `foo`, then `get_val() = x` would be like `foo = x`

Comment: After reading my previous comment I hope you can see how if `get_val` tries to return 10 it's nonsensical because it would be like assigning a value to `10`.  `10 = x` doesn't make sense.  So you really need a different implementation of `get_val` for this to make sense.  If you saw something like this in the wild, the `get_val` almost certainly returned a reference to some other variable or storage location.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600 for a comprehensive explanation of what's going on here.

Comment: "I know we cannot run this code but I want to learn the concept behind this" - This is a weird way of approaching things. "I know this doesn't work, but I want to know how it works." It doesn't. That's the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `get_val` function is defined as returning a reference to an integer; however, what you *actually* return is a reference to a *constant*, so any attempt to assign a value to that will not compile. In fact, the function itself (attempting to return a reference to `10`) won't compile; clang-cl gives this:

> error : non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a
> temporary of type 'int'

However, if you add a `static int`<sup>1</sup> inside your function, and return (a reference to) *that*, then you can use statements like `getval() = x;` to assign the value of `x` to that *internal* `static int` (which is otherwise 'invisible' outside the function).

Here's a short demonstration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int& get_val()
{
    static int inside = 42;
    std::cout << inside << "\n";
    return inside;
}

int main()
{
    get_val() = 5; // Prints INITIAL value of "inside" then (after the call) assigns
                   // the value 5 to it, via the returned reference
    get_val();     // Prints the modified value
    return 0;
}
```

The above example is trivial and would likely not serve any real-world purpose; it is purely for demonstration purposes. However, there *may* be cases where you would want a function to return a reference to any one of a number of different objects, depending on calculations and decisions made in that function; the selected, referenced object can then be suitably modified using code like that shown here.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `inside` variable needs to be declared as `static` so that:

1. Its lifetime does not end when the function returns (thus creating a [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46011510/10871073)).
2. Its value is maintained from one call to the next.