# How should I use thread_pool in this case?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, boost-asio

for example: when I write this code I recieve right result.

```
boost::asio::thread_pool t(3);
std::vector<int> vec = {10,20,30};
boost::asio::post(t, [&]{ foo(vec[0]);});
boost::asio::post(t, [&]{ foo(vec[1]);});
boost::asio::post(t, [&]{ foo(vec[2]);});
t.join();
```

but when i want use boost::asio::post in for-cicle i recieve error Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library:
"Expression: vector subscript out of range"

```
boost::asio::thread_pool t(3);
std::vector<int> vec = {10,20,30};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    boost::asio::post(t, [&]{ foo(vec[i]);});
}
t.join();
```

what can i do to make my last way return the correct answer?

Comment: "in for-cicle" - Huh? What does that mean?

Comment: i don't want to write boost::asio::post() multiple times and want to use it in for(){}...i do something crazy?)

Comment: You need to change your lambda capture to `[&,i]` (or more explicitly: `[&vec,i]`) - see explanation in @DrewDormann's comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are capturing `i` by reference for a lambda that is used asynchronously.  When `t.join();` is reached, `i` is a [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011510/what-is-a-dangling-reference).

Capture it by value so it doesn't change or expire.

```
boost::asio::post(t, [&,i]{ foo(vec[i]);});
```