# Don't understand how std::iterator works in list initialization

Tags: c++, iterator

I have trouble with using `std::vector::iterator`. First I defined a `struct`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct VecIter {
  VecIter(std::vector<T>::iterator &&it_, size_t remain_):
    it(it_), remain(remain_) {}

  std::vector<T>::iterator &it;
  size_t remain;

  T& operator * () {
    return *it;
  }
};
```

It's just a wrapper of a regular iterator. Here is a test class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class testA {
  public:
    testA(std::vector<T> &a) {
      stack.push_back({a.begin(), a.size()});
    }

    std::vector<VecIter<T>> stack;
};
```

The constructor takes a `std::vector` as input and initialize our iterator wrapper. Here comes the test section:

```
TEST(TestIterator, test_iter_in_stack) {
  std::vector<int> a{3, 2, 1};

  testA<int> sol(a);
  auto x = sol.stack[0];
 
  auto it = x.it;  // extract the iterator
  cout << *it << "\n";  // segmentation fault here...
  it++;
  cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

My question is why `*it` here would cause a segmentation fault? I suspect the list initialization `stack.push_back({a.begin(), a.size()})` didn't successfully pass the iterator in.

I expect the test should print out `3` and `2`. Any comments is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that you have made reference wrapper, initialise it with reference to temporary iterator object a.begin() that leaves scope after push_back. Then you  have tangling reference and undefined behaviour and demons out of your nose allowed.

Comment: [What is a dangling reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011510/what-is-a-dangling-reference)

Comment: Note that, despite the title, the question is about `std::vector::iterator`, not `std::iterator`. The latter is a helper that many people think is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VecIter::it` is a dangling reference to the temporary object returned by `a.begin()`. You should change `std::vector<T>::iterator &it` to `std::vector<T>::iterator it`.

In general, iterators are likely not much more than a pointer, passing and storing them by reference is not likely to be necessary. The standard library generally passes them by value, e.g. in the [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).